# How to test with cross-origin data in node-webkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain, node-webkit, getimagedata

I've been testing all of my cross-origin data through Node with much success. However, I recently ran into a situation where Node couldn't solve the request for data.

I'm using the **getImageData()** function, which throws the cross-origin problem. On other cross-origin problems, Node can successfully handle the requests, but this function seems to give it trouble.

Also, if I package it up with node-webkit and run it stand-alone, it works great. I'm sure there is an explanation, but I cannot find it. Why would node-webkit work, but running a Node.js server not?

Without pouring code all over this page, let me try to explain what I'm doing. I have an Axis Camera that I'm getting data from. It's Motion JPEG, and it get stored in the **img** tag that I've got ID'd. The data is coming from *http://ip*, etc, etc.

I think the problem is that the **getImageData()** function is requesting from the **img** tag ID rather than somewhere external, which would in-turn throw the cross-origin flag.

Am I correct?  How can I solve this?

Also, does anyone know of a good way to test node-webkit apps without actually packaging them?  Essentially, a node-webkit simulator?

Comment: When you use the term ['WebKit'](http://www.webkit.org/), do you mean the web browser engine that powers Chromium and Safari browsers, or do you mean ['node-webkit'](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), the app framework that enables the DOM to access Node.js modules for building desktop applications?

Comment: I've actually moved on to a different implementation, but I was talking about the "Node WebKit".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Brett, I went ahead and edited to make that more clear, since the two are completely different and are used for different things. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding this to the package.json:

```
"chromium-args": "--disable-web-security",
```

Try it!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, this basically means I must run my "app" with nw.exe each time I wish to test it because I'm beholden to the package.json file. Correct? Is there a way I can do the same thing when starting my node server... maybe something like **node server.js --disable-web-security**  ???

Comment: Gave it a check since it led me to an answer that I could work with. In order to debug this particular situation, I ended up using the "chromium-args" flag and the "window" flag. Its an easy way out, but now I'm just accessing the javascript console from inside webkit after it's launched. Thanks for the help!